# how to get date format Tue, Apr 29 '14. i need single quote in year

Tags: asp.net, date-format, datetime-format

how to get this date format `Tue, Apr 29 '14`. I need single quote in year, I have tried like this.

```
string dt = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Date"].ToString()).ToString("ddd, MMM dd ''yy");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to escape the quote using a backslash. To avoid escaping the backslash I have used *verbatim string literal* (prefixed with @):

```
@"ddd, MMM dd \'yy"
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifications with prefixed @. Solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date.ToString("ddd, MMM dd \"'\"yy")
```